# Azure WebJob returns "The system cannot find the file specified"

Tags: php, azure, azure-webjobs

Im trying to run a PHP script on Azure WebJobs. This worked perfectly earlier until recently when I was re-deploying an application. Now any PHP script I try to upload refuses to load giving me the following error errors on the logfile:

```
[05/01/2015 13:21:25 > 611c38: SYS INFO] Status changed to Initializing
[05/01/2015 13:21:25 > 611c38: SYS INFO] Run script 'test.php' with script host - 'PhpScriptHost'
[05/01/2015 13:21:25 > 611c38: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running
[05/01/2015 13:21:25 > 611c38: ERR ] The system cannot find the file specified
[05/01/2015 13:21:25 > 611c38: SYS INFO] Status changed to Failed
[05/01/2015 13:21:25 > 611c38: SYS ERR ] System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
   at Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.ProcessWrapper.Start()
   at Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.ProcessExtensions.<Start>d__a.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.Executable.<ExecuteAsync>d__1d.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
   at Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.Executable.ExecuteInternal(ITracer tracer, Func`2 onWriteOutput, Func`2 onWriteError, Encoding encoding, String arguments, Object[] args)
   at Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.Executable.ExecuteReturnExitCode(ITracer tracer, Action`1 onWriteOutput, Action`1 onWriteError, String arguments, Object[] args)
   at Kudu.Core.Jobs.BaseJobRunner.RunJobInstance(JobBase job, IJobLogger logger, String runId)
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
   at Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.ProcessWrapper.Start()
   at Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.ProcessExtensions.<Start>d__a.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.Executable.<ExecuteAsync>d__1d.MoveNext()<---
```

The problem persists on any web app I have deployed on Azure.

Comment: Looks like it cant find the file test.php Is that loaded onto the server in the right place?

Comment: Yes, it was uploaded as a zip file through the portal. I can verify that the php file is in its right location through FTP to Azure.

Comment: You have checked the permissions on the file and the directory

Comment: I don't think I'm able to manage permissions on that file, however I've checked through FileZilla and made sure everyone has read access to it. The problem is still there.

Comment: Its quite difficult to tell from this, but the error is telling you that it cannot find a file. So double check that test.php and any files that test.php references are included in the zip that you uploaded. I found this [http://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/) helpfull

Comment: It is indeed unclear what file it is looking for as it doesn't even say what file its looking for. I have made a new webjob with a zip containing run.php as files named run is the first file Azure starts looking for. However, the problem is still there.

Comment: it says its looking for test.php.

Comment: That was in the old WebJob. Like I said earlier, I made a new WebJob that should run run.php. The logs on Azure says it attempts to execute run.php (run.php EXISTS through FileZilla), and then it says that it couldn't find some file. What file it can't find isn't specified. Here is the log for the NEW web job: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=ewmFYnQr.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76711/discussion-between-jon-c-and-martin).

Answer (score 3):

check php runtime is installed ;)

Answer (score 2):

The issue was that the php support was disabled on the dashboard. Azure was able to find my php script and it had rights to read it. When it tried to execute the script, it wouldn't be able to find the runtime as it was disabled through the dashboard. Could have saved me for a few hours of work if it could say that php was disabled instead of saying that it can't find some file.

Always make sure that the script runtime for the script you are executing is enabled on the portal.